# remove label after it fades away

Tags: xcode, swift

I have this code here where I show the label, have it fade away(which orks up to here) and then I want to remove it. Everything works fine untill i want to remove it. I need to remove it so i can run the whole process again.
Here is my code:

```
        view.addSubview(minusLabel)
        UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseIn, animations: {
            self.minusLabel.alpha = 0
            }, completion: {
                (finished: Bool) -> Void in
                self.minusLabel.removeFromSuperview()
        }
        )
```

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: removing the label from the view after it fades away

Comment: I see the line `self.minusLabel.removeFromSuperview()`. That is exactly what it does. You can use `self.minusLabel.alpha = 1` to reset the `alpha` so that you will be able to see it again. Removing the label from the view does not reset any of the label's properties.

Comment: ohhh so it is removed but the alfa is still 0?

Comment: When it is removed and added back the alpha value is still 0, you need to have it set back to 1 when the function finishes

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to remove the the label to repeat the animation, try this code instead, and modify it to your likings:

```
        func animate() {

            UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, animations: {
            self.label.alpha = 1.0
            //label is the name of your label which you have defined/created

                }, completion: {
                    (Completed: Bool) -> Void in

                    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveLinear, animations: {

                        self.label.alpha = 0
                        //label is the name of your label which you have defined/created

                        }, completion: {
                            (Completed: Bool) -> Void in

                            self.animate()
            })

            })

        }
```

Whenever you want to call this function, use `animate()` and below it add `label.alpha = 0` (Change label to the name of your label). Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iyg3u3z_fKI